# Conda Init zsh No action taken

Tags: linux, anaconda, debian, virtual-machine, zsh

I am trying to start conda in Linux, when I want to add zsh which is the terminal it sends me that error and I can't continue. Does anyone know how I can fix this. I already tried with
conda deactivate
conda activate Test1
and still the same error. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dg5vO.png)

Resolve the problem

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Don't post screenshots unnecessarily. You could equally well copy and paste your command and the error message as text. Also, you better explain how you did set up _conda_.